# Firebase connect not available Android Studio 3.2

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

When I try and connect up Firebase in Android Studio, I am getting a null exception. First off, there is no "Firebase" selection under the "Tools" tab, so I have to search Android studio for it. When it comes up from the search and I click on "Firebase" I get an error message that says:

```
Exception in plugin Firebase Services. Moments ago. Occurred once since the last clear. Unread.
```

With this Java exception in the little pop up box that goes along with it:

```
null
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$1.next(Iterators.java:81)
    at com.google.services.firebase.DependencyStateManager.getDependencyState(DependencyStateManager.java:59)
    at com.google.services.firebase.DependencyStateManager.init(DependencyStateManager.java:108)
    at com.android.tools.idea.assistant.view.StatefulButton.<init>(StatefulButton.java:98)
    at com.android.tools.idea.assistant.view.TutorialStep.<init>(TutorialStep.java:113)
    at com.android.tools.idea.assistant.view.TutorialCard.redraw(TutorialCard.java:163)
    at com.android.tools.idea.assistant.view.TutorialCard.<init>(TutorialCard.java:94)
    at com.android.tools.idea.assistant.view.FeaturesPanel.<init>(FeaturesPanel.java:84)
    at com.android.tools.idea.assistant.AssistSidePanel.<init>(AssistSidePanel.java:81)
    at com.android.tools.idea.assistant.AssistToolWindowFactory.createToolWindowContent(AssistToolWindowFactory.java:37)
    at com.android.tools.idea.assistant.OpenAssistSidePanelAction.lambda$openWindow$0(OpenAssistSidePanelAction.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:315)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.doRun(LaterInvocator.java:447)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:431)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:415)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:822)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:763)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:423)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

What am I doing wrong here? I've never connected Firebase to Android Studio before on this Macbook Pro.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Windows system. This worked for me:

Try to uncheck All firebase plugins under File > Settings > Plugins

[image]

Click ok, it will restart the IDE.

After that repeat the same process, checking and installing the firebase plugins again. Your IDE will be restarted.